# How to get an alert message if a particular radio button is selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, radio-button, selection

As you may have know, '.radio4' is a class and it was assigned some
value. If '.radio4' is clicked then it must show an alert message."

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.radio4').click(function(){
    if($(this). is(':checked')){
        alert('Hello');
    });
  });   
});
```

Comment: use `change` not `click` on checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use class or input `name` to check the value. You could show your value like this the following. I'm using `yourRadioName` as an example name. Here's a https://jsfiddle.net/03tepqxq/17/

```
alert($('input[name=yourRadioName]').val());
```

or with your class:

```
alert($('.radio4').val());
```

Or with your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=yourRadioName]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('Hello');
    }
  });   
});
```

Comment: How did you get to this answer without the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum, so did not know how to include the html code.  It is a multiple choice question...Ex: World Smallest Country with 4 options as answers..so when Option D. Vatican City is selected. It should alert "Correct!",   <div class = "radio4">
       <label><input type = "radio" name = optradio"> D. Vatican City</label>
     </div>
Sorry, if it is confusing!!

Comment: @NigelAngel I added a fiddle to my example. It works fine.

Comment: Since you fixed it according to popnoodles answer yes

Comment: @bklynM - I'm not sure you really answered the question here and I think that's what the other commenters are driving at. There might be very good reasons why the OP is binding to `class` and not `name`, though the OP really should explain *what they are trying to do*, not what they've done which is not working

Comment: @wahwahwah Yeah that's a fair comment. My assumption was that the class wasn't specific enough, but that may or may not be the case. Thanks

Comment: I am getting the alert message! but other options are also getting selected.

Comment: @bklynM, the alert message is popping over, but I added else statement, I mean, if any other option other than the correct answer is selected, it should display "wrong msg", but it is not working, can you please go over it.

Comment: @lcritic I updated the fiddle in my answer. You Should have a  input 'name' for each radio option so you can do something with that value, so when the one you are checking is clicked that one will alert, otherwise nothing.

Comment: @bklynM, if you first click on the second option, then both the options are getting clicked, rather than one option, where only one option is supposed to be checked.

Comment: @lcritic See the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/03tepqxq/17/. You need to use the same name for both options in the set, and then checking for the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says what the given code almost does.. So I assume it's the syntax error that's the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.radio4').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('Hello');
    } // <-- this should not have a closing )
  });   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qcobm5as/

However, you should use `change` on radios and checkboxes

```
$('.radio4').change(function(){
```